# why .lastIndexOf won't work? lastIndexOf functioning like indexOf

Tags: javascript

I want to get the last "o" from right to left, using .lastIndexOf().
But it always returns the index (1). as far as I know it should show (1) only if I use indexOf, intead of lastIndexOf();. I expected to get the index)(10).

```
let nome = "Robin Singh";

let resultado = nome.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("o");

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: It returns the index of the last match. It doesn't count from the end, it's still a normal index.

Comment: Why would you want it to return `10`? How would you use that to access the element?

Comment: To see the difference between `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`, look for `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lastIndexOf** does not work likes that. The different between **indexOf** & **lastIndexOf** is -
**indexOf** starts searching from left.And **lastIndexof** starts searching from right.

But you Can get your desire result like this:

```js
let nome = "Robin Singh";

let resultado = nome.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().indexOf('o');

console.log(resultado);
```

It will return `9`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want this, but you can just subtract the result from the length of the original string.

`String.prototype.lastIndexOf` returns the index of the last instance, starts from the left where `i = 0`

```js
let nome = "Robin Singh";

let resultado = nome.length - nome.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("o");

console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

The index returned is an index that can be used to access the character in the original string (zero-indexed counting from left to right). If you want to get 10, you can subtract the result from the string's length.

```js
let nome = "Robin Singh";
let resultado = nome.length - nome.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("o");
console.log(resultado);
```